# await operator does not wait for promise fulfillment value instead returns unrenderable promise object

Tags: reactjs, async-await, next.js

Im running the latest next.js release (13) and encountered a problem where the await operator seems to be ignored. My file:

```
"use client"
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
async function getData(parsedUrl) {
    
    const platform = parsedUrl.searchParams.get("platform");
    const stock = parsedUrl.searchParams.get("stock");
    const score = parsedUrl.searchParams.get("score");
    const type = parsedUrl.searchParams.get("type");
    
    if (platform !== null && stock !== null && score !== null && type !== null) {
    
        const url = `http://localhost:3001/checkout/normalMultiple?platform=${platform}&stock=${stock}&score=${score}&type=${type}`;
      
        const res = await fetch(url, {cache: 'no-store'}); 
        const data = await res.json();
        return data;
    }
}

export default async function CheckoutPage() {
    if (typeof window == "undefined") {
        return(<div>We not ready</div>)
    }
    const parsedUrl = new URL(window.location.href);

    console.log('parsedUrl', parsedUrl)

    const scores = await getData(parsedUrl);
    
    console.log('scores:', scores)
    console.log('type of scores:', typeof scores);
    console.log('scores is array:', Array.isArray(scores))
    
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Checkout </h1>
            <ul>
                {scores?.map((score) => (
                    <li key={score.shareTicker}>{score.stockName}</li>
                )
                )}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )   
      
    
}
```

My error message:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Since nextjs 13 is so new, I can't find solutions for this. I do not want to use useEffect to solve this. Solutions and ways to improve my code appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Components can't be `async` that's the problem. It's `CheckoutPage` that is the promise in the error

Comment: they can, thats the new thing: https://youtu.be/__mSgDEOyv8?t=228
Still this helped me. It seems like async and "use client" doesn't work together.

Comment: This is server-side only feature but you are right

Comment: Thanks, Konrad. I have another problem.. How can I get this working when window is undefined on the first render? With useEffect it would just render again once I have the url params but now I only get ```return(<div>We not ready</div>)```.

Comment: You can't access `window` in server component [`Use browser-only APIs ❌`](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#when-to-use-server-vs-client-components)

Comment: Yes I figured that. I used ``useSearchParams()`` which gives me the params but still nextjs crashes, it's a shame.